# Singular they - How old are/is they?

Tags: grammatical-number, they

I was wondering, because I couldn’t find that information anywhere, which version would be correct.

Let’s suppose somebody is telling me about :-) their :-) friend. I don’t know anything about the gender of that friend yet and I want to know how old... and here’s the question:

> 1. (...) how old they are.
> 2. (...) how old they is.

It’s about one specific friend that I don’t know the gender of.

Of course I could ask: „How old is your friend?” Or „How old is he or she?” but I’d like to use Singular they if possible.

So, should I ask: "How old is they?" or "How old are they?"? Or maybe Singular they doesn’t work here?

Comment: *They* is always plural (i.e. plural agreement). :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English:

> ‘They’ can be used when talking about someone who may be male or female, to
>   avoid saying ‘he or she’:
>
> If anyone has any information related to the crime, will they please
>   contact the police.
>
> Every **child**, whoever **they are**, deserves to have a mum and a
>   dad.
>
> People do this in order to avoid suggesting that the person can only
>   be male, or to avoid using longer expressions such as 'he or she',
>   'him or her'. This use is acceptable and very common in spoken
>   English, and is becoming more acceptable in writing as well. However,
>   some people consider this use to be incorrect. You can sometimes avoid
>   the problem by making the subject plural.

Considering the words in bold, one should use "singular they" with plural verbs.